# MySQL Query Error 'Data Truncated...'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try to insert values into one of my tables, one particular value is causing 'Error Code:1265, Data truncated for...' i think due the last columns quote ('). When escaping with the backslash, I still get the same error.

Note: The value "String's" is contained within a set. This is the only query of many causing the error.

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES
    ('String',1,'String','String','String's');  

INSERT INTO Table VALUES
    ('String',1,'String','String','String\'s');  

INSERT INTO Table VALUES
    ('String',1,'String','String','String''s');
```

All of the above return the same error.

Why might this be?

Comment: The first statement needs the quote escaped with \ or add another quote to it  `'String''s'` or use the function QUOTE.Quotes need to be escaped because they are string and date delimiters

Comment: @Mihai Sorry I should have explained, both statements are returning the same error (even with the backslash)

Comment: James, are you adding a string of length above the ones specified as MAX in the table? Maybe the last Column is `varchar(6)` and you're adding a string of 7 characters, for example.

Comment: In that case your column size might be too short for the length of the string.My first comment still stands as it is.Show the real statement and the table definition.`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`